# Why does a <button> on Comment edit page submit the page?

Tags: javascript, comments, forms

I followed [this guide to add a "copy to clipboard" button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp) on the edit Comment page (comment.php?action=editcomment)

It works but it also submits the page (i.e. the page reloads back to the comments list) but I don't understand why.

This is the html:
`<input type="hidden" value="This is copied" id="civicrm-subject-code-field"><button class="ed_button button button-small" onclick="copy_civicrm_subject_code()">Copy</button>`

This is the JS:

```
async function copy_civicrm_subject_code() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("civicrm-subject-code-field");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();

   /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the entire comment edit page is inside a `<form>` element, and the `<button>` element submits any form that it belongs to. This is the normal behaviour of buttons in HTML.

If you don't want a button to act as a submit button, you need to set the `type` attribute to `button`:

```
<button class="ed_button button button-small" onclick="copy_civicrm_subject_code()" type="button">
  Copy
</button>
```

The default `type` attribute for a button is `submit`, which is why it behaves that way unless you set it to `button`.

Comment: I knew it would be something like this. And I looked for exactly that information but had no luck. Or possibly my ADHD kicked in and I forgot what I was looking for ‍♀️